# Installing brew on Mac OS 10.12 getting xcode license agreement error

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on Mac 10.12 with the command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

On running this, I am getting an error:

```
You have not agreed to the Xcode license.
Before running the installer again please agree to the license by opening
Xcode.app or running:
    sudo xcodebuild -license
```

So I run `sudo xcodebuild -license` command then again got another error which is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation: cannot load '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation' because Objective-C garbage collection is not supported
Please review and agree to the software license agreements!
```

I looked into this error also but no luck. While looking into this, I tried to reinstall xcode with the command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then I check for xcode installation by:

```
/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path
```

The path printed, which seems to be correct, is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now can please somebody help me in accepting license agreement for xcode? This is where I am stuck and not able to move forward. Any suggestions or my error correction will be commendable.

Comment: Not on the command line but if you start Xcode (the app, from launchpad or applications dir) the license agreement should also pop up.

Comment: Thanks @jonhopkins for the editing! I tried that also. On opening xcode from application getting an error that xcode 4.4.2 is not supported with current mac os. So i updated it to xcode 8. Now able to accept the agreement license through GUI and brew gets installed.

Comment: @RajniGangwar It seems like useful information that OSX 10.12 doesn't support Xcode 4.4.2. You should make an answer out of what you found out, in case other people run into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have OSX 10.12 then xcode version 4.4.2 will not work with that in either way by a terminal or GUI. First try to update your xcode with the compatible version. **Xcode 8 will be supported with OSX 10.11 and above.**

Comment: ...ouch... so now I have to downgrade OSX or run a VM just to run this build. :/